# How to convert a software RAID 1 partition to non-RAID partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, software-raid, raid-1

RAID is not a backup, they say, but only now I can see that what I really need is an (external) backup.

So, I would like to convert a (software) RAID-1 partition to a non-RAID partition (ext4) in my Linux system (Debian 7), but I am clueless how to do it.

My goal is to remove one of the two internal drives of the current RAID 1 setup and use it as a external backup drive, so I can preserve the data on another physical place.

Is there any way to do this conversion to non-RAID without formatting the current RAID partition (/home) in the (future) single internal drive?

Thanks for any advice,
Marcio

Comment: What software are you using? *mdadm* or similar?

Comment: I am using mdadm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do to safely remove a RAID-1 managed by mdadm:

1. Run `fdisk -l`. This will tell you how many and which arrays you have. In following steps, I'm assuming you only have `/dev/md0`.
2. Run `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`. This will give you information about which physical disks are in use.
3. Run `umount -l /dev/md0`, which will allow you to later stop your RAID. 
   The `-l` flag will do the following, as per its man page:

   > -l     Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierarchy now, and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon as
   >   it is not busy anymore. (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)
4. Run `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`. This will stop your RAID array.
5. Erase the superblock on each device in the RAID (should be detailed in the command run in step 2).

   ```
   mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda
   mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb
   ...
   ```

That should be it.

Comment: nKn, thank you for your answer, but I could not make it work here. I believe it´s due to the fact that md0 is root partition and md1 is home partition. I don't know any way to stop root partition. I have tried booting from another disk but on the --zero-superblock step I got a message saying that the partition was not available to write.

Comment: You can boot your machine from a LiveCD like Finnix, for instance, and manage it from there.

Comment: nKn, I have tried with a LiveCD but could not access the disk. My RAID system started to fail some days ago, and I made a backup and tried your sugestions, but could not make it work. I have decided to format the disks, give up of RAID, set one internal disk only for /home and the other disk (of the previous RAID) will become an external backup unit. Another smaller disk is now my /boot/root/var. Thank you again for your time and kindness.

Comment: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sda  ???

Comment: Instead of issuing ```fdisk -l```  and ```mdadm --detail ...```, you may use ```cat /proc/mdstat``` which prints all existing ```md*``` together with their members at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

`mdadm --zero-superblock` may not be enough, the partition information may need to be updated, too.

What worked for me to successfully convert an 8TB drive with one `mdadm` RAID1 GPT partition `/dev/sda1` formatted with XFS to a "regular" drive/partition is:

1. `cat /proc/mdstat` shows all your RAID devices and their components, e.g.

```
...
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[2] sda1[1]
      7813893952 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
...
```

1. To convert `/dev/sda1` of RAID device `/dev/md0` to a regular drive first `umount /dev/md0`.
2. Then `mdadm --stop /dev/md0` to stop the RAID.
3. `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1` converts to "regular" drive/partition.
4. Change file system type with `fdisk` to `20` (Linux filesystem).
5. Fix partition table with `testdisk /dev/sda`.

This should work for an Ext4 file system also.